# lime test windows error command prompt not installed?

Tags: haxeflixel

Everytime i load command prompt this always happens:
Me: cd Documents/Funkin-master
Me: Lime test windows
Error: You must have a "project.xml" file or specify another valid project file when using the 'test' command.
There is a Project.xml and I need to uninstall HaxeFlixel and reinstall a different version.
Someone help me please.
I WANNA MAKE MY OWN MOD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do `"cd Documents/Funkin-master/Funkin-master"` because I think you led to a directory that does not, in fact, have a project.xml. `"cd Documents/Funkin-master"` I think is just a folder containing a folder.

Oh! Also, if you need to update haxeflixel, the command is `"haxelib update flixel"`.